# Define a style in tabularray

Tags: tabularray

I've just discovered [tabularray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) and i love it.

The use of keys to parameter my (x300) tables is made easy.

However, I miss something in the documentation.

We can define

```
\NewTblrTheme{fancy}{  
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead}{default}{[Continued]}  
\SetTblrStyle{firsthead}{font=\bfseries}  
\SetTblrStyle{firstfoot}{fg=blue2}  
\SetTblrStyle{middlefoot}{\itshape}  
\SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{red2}}
```

for some features of the tables that can be used by callin `[theme = fancy]`.

But how can I create something (like styles) for other elements

```
mystyle1/.style = {
        colspec = {rX[c]X[c]X[c]}, 
        width = 0.75\linewidth,
        row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
        column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
        row{odd} = {green!10}, 
        row{even} = {green!20}, 
}
```

```
mystyle2/.style = {
        colspec = {rXXX}, 
        width = \linewidth,
        % row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
        % column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
        row{odd} = {blue!10}, 
        row{even} = {blue!20}, 
}
```

[image]

Can I also control inside this style the behavior of `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` ?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{ %mystyle1 %mystyle2 
        colspec = {rX[c]X[c]X[c]}, 
        width = 0.75\linewidth,
        row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
        column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
        row{odd} = {green!10}, 
        row{even} = {green!20}, 
    }
                    
    \toprule
    & S\&P & Fitch & Moody's \\ 
    \midrule
    Prime & AAA & AAA & Aaa \\ 
    \multirow{3}{*}{High grade} & AA+ & AA+ & Aa1 \\ 
    & AA & AA & Aa2 \\ 
    & AA- & AA- & Aa3 \\ 
    \multirow{3}{*}{Upper medium grade} & A+ & A+ & A1 \\ 
    & A & A & A2 \\ 
    & A- & A- & A3 \\ 
    \multirow{3}{*}{Lower medium grade} & BBB+ & BBB+ & Baa1 \\ 
    & BBB & BBB & Baa2 \\ 
    & BBB- & BBB- & Baa3 \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic:  command `\multirow{3}{*}{...}` will be with new realize of `tabularray`  (at March 1st) obsolete. Use `tabularray` replacement `\SetCell[r=3]{bg=green!10}  ...`  instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\NewTblrEnviron` to define a new environment, and use `\SetTblrInner` to set the default styles:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\NewTblrEnviron{mytblr}
\SetTblrOuter[mytblr]{long}
\SetTblrInner[mytblr]{
  colspec = {rX[c]X[c]X[c]}, 
  width = 0.85\linewidth,
  row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
  column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
  row{odd} = {green!10}, 
  row{even} = {green!20},
  rowhead = 1,
  hline{1,Z} = {0.08em}, % toprule and bottomrule
  hline{2} = {0.05em}, % midrule  
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytblr}[
  caption = {My Caption},
]{
  % more specs
}                    
    & S\&P & Fitch & Moody's \\ 
    Prime & AAA & AAA & Aaa \\ 
\SetCell[r=3]{r}High grade & AA+ & AA+ & Aa1 \\ 
    & AA & AA & Aa2 \\ 
    & AA- & AA- & Aa3 \\ 
\SetCell[r=3]{r}Upper medium grade & A+ & A+ & A1 \\ 
    & A & A & A2 \\ 
    & A- & A- & A3 \\ 
\SetCell[r=3]{r}Lower medium grade & BBB+ & BBB+ & Baa1 \\ 
    & BBB & BBB & Baa2 \\ 
    & BBB- & BBB- & Baa3 \\ 
\end{mytblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this great package ! Get ready for other question :)

Answer (score 7):

### Second Version *(better names and error message)*

Use the `\DefTblrInnerStyle` macro to define a style (locally).
To apply a defined style, use the `style` key in the mandatory argument of `tblr` environment.

```LaTeX
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\pagestyle{empty}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_gput_left:Nn \g__tblr_table_known_keys_clist { style }
\keys_define:nn { tblr } { style .code:n = \__tblr_apply_style:n { #1 } }
\msg_new:nnn { tblr } { undefined inner style } { undefined ~ tblr ~ inner ~ style ~ '#1' ! }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tblr_apply_style:n #1 {
  \tl_if_exist:cTF { l__tblr_inner_style_ #1 _tl } {
    \keys_set:nv { tblr } { l__tblr_inner_style_ #1 _tl }
  } {
    \msg_error:nnn { tblr } { undefined inner style } { #1 }
  }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \DefTblrInnerStyle { m m } {
  \tl_clear_new:c { l__tblr_inner_style_ #1 _tl }
  \tl_set:cx { l__tblr_inner_style_ #1 _tl } { #2 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\DefTblrInnerStyle{test 1}{row{1}={r,bg=blue!50},column{2}={fg=red}}
\DefTblrInnerStyle{test 2}{row{1}={l,bg=lime},column{2}={fg=blue}}
\DefTblrInnerStyle{test 3}{style=test 1,style=test 2}
{
  \DefTblrInnerStyle{test 3}{style=test 2,style=test 1}
  \begin{tblr}{colspec={ccc},style=test 3,hlines,vlines}
    abbb & b & c \\
    a & baba & cdsdd
  \end{tblr}
}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={ccc},style=test 3,hlines,vlines}
  abbb & b & c \\
  a & baba & cdsdd
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh I like your style Paul :)

Comment: @JeT I edited my answer to make the definition of styles local.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for commands inside the argument. For example, `font=\bfseries` returns an error. Could this be fixed?

Comment: Maybe with `\tl_set:cn` instead of `\tl_set:cx`?

Comment: @Sam It seems to me easier to prevent the expansion of certain elements than to ask for the expansion of the value if it is not done...